# codeigniter/sql/ adding WHERE to $table

Tags: sql, ajax, codeigniter, datatable, pagination

```
$now=time();
$sTable ='cupons 
            LEFT JOIN includes ON cupons.offer_includes =  includes.cupon_includes_i' ;
```

$sTable is 2 sql tables joined in one variable. I need to add WHERE to that variable that is end_date

Comment: **Unclear what you're asking**

Comment: I don't know why you are not using codeigniter active records query instead of writing like this.

Also one thing, if you are thinking to add WHERE on the field of left joined table, then it will not work according to sql rules.